# SQL Query for data moved from No-SQL Database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a No-SQL DB with the following attributes. I am planning to move this to SQL as it is mostly used for OLAP.

Can I perform the following query here : The avg. time taken to move from State **Initiated** to **UnderReview**.The catch is customer can have multiple entries with same state (Version will be different).For each customer, I want to select the time with latest version.

For this table, answer would be :

(T3 - T1 + T7 - T6)/2

Any pointers would be appreciated.

| CustomerId | State | Version | Time |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | Initiated | 1 | T1 |  |
| C1 | UnderReview | 2 | T2 |  |
| C1 | UnderReview | 3 | T3 |  |
| C1 | Completed | 4 | T4 |  |
| C2 | Initiated | 1 | T6 |  |
| C2 | UnderReview | 2 | T7 |  |

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate with a filter across a `customerid` to get up to one `Initiated` and up to one `UnderReview`.  It's up to you whether you want to use the first or last value in your calculation.  Adjust the `min()` or `max()` to meet your requirements.

After that, `avg()` will perform the calculation for you.

```
with prog as (
  select customerid,
         min(time) filter (where state = 'Initiated') as first_init,
         max(time) filter (where state = 'UnderReview') as last_review
    from your_table
   group by customerid
)
select avg(last_review - first_init) 
  from prog
 where last_review is not null
   and first_init is not null;
```